# How to remove 4 pixel padding after a word?

Tags: html, css, padding, spacing

[image: What is happening]

In the above picture there is a 4 pixel padding after the word Contact and when not selected it looks like there is a 5 pixel padding between the divider and feedback and a 9 pixel padding between contact and the divider. How can I get rid of those 4 pixels after Contact?

Edit: Here's some code.

```
.vdivider {
    width: 1px;
    height: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #666666;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}

<div id="footer">
    <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    <span class="vdivider"></span>
    <a href="feedback.php">Site Feedback</a>
</div>
```

Comment: We need to see some code. The only thing you can do to a screenshot is to edit the extra padding out with an image editor, I guess.

Comment: @BoltClock That was a genius response. But yes, could you show the code? Perhaps the markup is a little messed, or the CSS.

Comment: Is it there with every font you have tried?

Comment: Then Moses' solution is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing your code would help tremendously, but I think I can guess what the issue is without it.

You are using padding-right to separate list items, and are using a 1px border as a separator. The problem with this technique is white space insertion. If you remove all white space from your list, this will be solved. So either format your code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Contact</li><li>Site Feedback</li><li>Another Example</li>
</ul>
```

Or like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Contact</li><!-- prevent white space insertion
    --><li>Site Feedback</li><!-- prevent white space insertion
    --><li>Another Example</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** After seeing your code, I would suggest refactoring your code to the much more semantic version: an inline list. Again, this is just a suggestion. Let me know if you want more details on creating this effect using inline lists and I'll post working code for you.

**EDIT2:** http://jsfiddle.net/EqSBT/1/

Comment: Actually, I love refactoring code! I am always looking for ways to improve my coding style as I am still quite new to web programming. I'd be very appreciative if you would do this for me =D

Comment: @John Smith added a jsfiddle example to my answer. It is fully commented and explains pretty much everything. http://jsfiddle.net/EqSBT/1/